# Компиляция Python-скриптов с ресурсами в комплекте с помощью Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

У меня есть скрипт (оконное приложение) на Python. Как я могу при компиляции скрипта в .exe-файл "встроить" в него ресурсы - спрайты, шрифты и прочее - чтобы при запуске не бросалось исключение `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: А файлы рядом с exe положить вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Amgarak, к сожалению, не устраивает. "Нужен один исполняемый файл и ничего более" (цитата).

Comment: могу предложить костыль: запакуйте через паинсталлер;) будет работать инфа сотка - вес правда лишней накинет, но зато самый простой из всех способов:))